# EKS IAM service role not resolving for iceberg table access which is in another aws account

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I'm trying to access an iceberg table in a different AWS account and my query is running in an EKS cluster node group which is not able to resolve service IAM role. Instead, it is resolving to the EC2 IAM node even after specifying the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog.warehouse", "s3://internal/iceberg/warehouse/") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.iceberg_catalog.http-client.type", "apache") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.glue.catalogid", "67297262392") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:0.14.0,software.amazon.awssdk:bundle:2.17.131,software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.17.131") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I tried with DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain which mentioned in document that this will resolve to WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider but in my case this is not happening.

I cannot use assumeRole due to some concerns.